# Reverse Polish Notation on booleans

Tags: java, polish

Heloo. I am trying to implement a java code that will return me true or false depending on my imput. 
For example if i have 
true AND NOT( false AND true) AND NOT TRUE it should return FALSE

I tried to parse my imput String and to reorder the elements into the polish notation first then, evaluate the polish form. If i don't have NOT anywere, it works perfectly

But if i have 
true AND NOT( (false or false) AND (true OR false)) AND NOT TRUE
it returns TRUE but it should return false.

after i run the getPolishForm() function, my RPF looks like this

true false false OR true false OR AND true NOT AND NOT AND

I see that the problem is on the second NOT because it negates all this part ( (false or false) AND (true OR false)) AND NOT TRUE
but it should negate just the content in the paranthesys.

This is the function that  returns a list of strings in the polsih form

```
  ArrayList<String> getPolishForm() {
    ArrayList<String> postFix = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (infixForm == null)
        return null;
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < infixForm.size(); i++) {
        switch (new Priority(infixForm.get(i)).getValue()) {
        case 3:
            while (!stack.empty() && (stack.peek().equals("AND"))) {
                postFix.add(stack.pop());
            }
            stack.push(infixForm.get(i));
            break;
        case 4:
            stack.push(infixForm.get(i));
            break;
        case 1:
            stack.push(infixForm.get(i));
            break;
        case 2:
            while (!stack.empty() && !stack.peek().equals("LPARAN")) {
                postFix.add(stack.pop());
            }
            stack.pop();
            break;
        case 5:
            stack.push(infixForm.get(i));
            break;

        default:
            postFix.add(infixForm.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        postFix.add(stack.pop());
    }

    return postFix;
}
```

And This is the funtion that evaluates the RPF

```
Boolean getResult() {
    Stack<Boolean> stack = new Stack<Boolean>();
    boolean result = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < postFix.size(); i++) {
        if (isExpression(postFix.get(i))) {
            stack.push(new ReMatcher(postFix.get(i), tags).isMatch());//this line processes the string from the infixForm and returns a boolean

        } else {
            boolean op1 = stack.pop();
            try {
                boolean op2 = stack.pop();

                String operator = postFix.get(i);
                if (operator.equals("NOT")) {
                    op1 = !op1;
                    i++;
                    operator = postFix.get(i);
                }

                if (operator.equals("OR") )
                    result = op1 || op2;

                } else if (operator.endsWith("AND") )
                    result = op1 && op2;

            } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
                result = !op1;
            }
            stack.push(result);
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();
```

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: when you evaluate `not`, you already poped op1 and op2. There is only one op for `not`. You need to handle the `not` first, simply with `stack.push(!op1)`, then, only if the operator is not `not`, pop `op2`, and perform the operation as normal

Comment: (also, the posted code does not compile)

Comment: We're not going to debug your copy-pasted code for you. Isolate to problem to the absolute minimum code and input required to reproduce the problem, then request a reopen

Comment: and finally, you have a priority problem. `NOT( (false or false) AND (true OR false)) AND NOT TRUE` in your RPF is considered as `NOT [( (false or false) AND (true OR false)) AND NOT TRUE]`, which is `true`, so your whole expression at the end is `true AND true`

Comment: Thank you for your awnsers. I made a rearangement if the NOT values and now it works :)